# how to parse values plist file

Tags: iphone, plist

I am new in iPhone application development. I am developing now iPhone application. In this application i am used plist (property list) formate is given bellow.

```
Row
   ( item 0
          {
            title key   string  Africa

            children
            (
            item 0
            {
                title  string Baobab
                Children
                (
                   item 0
                   {
                     Image        string    imagename,
                     Plant Name   String    plantname,
                     Description  String    discription,
                     Note         String    Note, 
                   }
                )
            }
            item 1
            {
                title  string Baobab
                Children
                (
                   item 0
                   {
                     Image        string    imagename,
                     Plant Name   String    plantname,
                     Description  String    discription,
                     Note         String    Note, 
                   }
                )

             }
          )
       }
      item 0
          {
            title key   string  America

            children
            (
            item 0
            {
                title  string title_name1
                Children
                (
                   item 0
                   {
                     Image        string    imagename,
                     Plant Name   String    plantname,
                     Description  String    discription,
                     Note         String    Note, 
                   }
                )
            }
            item 1
            {
                title  string title_name2
                Children
                (
                   item 0
                   {
                     Image        string    imagename,
                     Plant Name   String    plantname,
                     Description  String    discription,
                     Note         String    Note, 
                   }
                )

             }
          )
       }   
  )
```

Now i need to parse this values separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading plists like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"your.plist"];
```

And then you can work with plist like with NSDictionary

```
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
for (NSString *key in keys)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [dict objectForKey:key];
    NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your .plist files is nothing but a NSDictionary representation. Once the content is loaded in Dictionary you can access it normally.